# Error in knn: NA/NaN/Inf in foreign function call (arg 6)

Tags: r

What is the meaning of this error, when I use `knn`:

```
g=summary(knn(train, test, l, k = 3))
Error in knn(train, test, l, k = 3) :
  NA/NaN/Inf in foreign function call (arg 6)

In addition: Warning messages:
1: In knn(train, test, l, k = 3) : NAs introduced by coercion
2: In knn(train, test, l, k = 3) : NAs introduced by coercion
```

Comment: Do you have any missing value either in `train` or `test`?

Comment: thanks some values are given as N/A .I think that's is the problem

Comment: possible duplicate of [Error with knn function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16874038/error-with-knn-function)

Comment: Probably due to having non-numeric data fields. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16874038/error-with-knn-function).